# Razor white page when render server side commands(Asp.net 5)?

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

First of all sorry my bad english.

When I try to view the url `/` for my `HomeController` and an `Index` action, all I get is a white page.

I'm starting from the empty ASP.NET 5 Web Application template and then I'm adding `Controllers\HomeController.cs`. Next, I'm adding the `Home` folder under `Views and finally adding`Index.cshtml`under`Views\Home`.

When I use `TempData["isim"]` it displays a blank page.

Why isn't there anything showing up?

**Startup.cs:**

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNet.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace WebApplication17
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseMvc(routes => routes.MapRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{ation=Index}"));
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args) => WebApplication.Run<Startup>(args);
    }
}
```

**Index.cshtml (working):**

```
<div>
    my welcome page
</div>
```

**Index.cshtml (not working):**

```
<div>
    my welcome page

    @{
        <input type="text" id="isim" />
        string ad = TempData["isim"] as string;
        <input type="submit" />
    }
</div>
```

[Screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4tVJ.jpg)

Comment: would you please post the code instead of screenshots? would be easier top help you, thanks.

Comment: rewrote your post and transformed the screen captures into properly formatted code. Please... please... no screen capture of code anymore. It takes too much time to rewrite for everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you very much @Maxime Rouiller. I solve the problem with your help. If i can't add developer exception catch errors, I cant see the problem and i cant find solutions.

The solutions is following codes below:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace WebApplication17
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc(); 
            services.AddSession(); // problem and solution is here
            services.AddCaching(); // problem and solution is here

        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage(); //thanks Maxime Rouiller.
            app.UseSession(); // problem and solution is here
            app.UseMvc(routes => routes.MapRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}"));
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args) => WebApplication.Run<Startup>(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

An exception is probably occuring.

Please add `app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();` in your `Configure()` method of your `Startup.cs`.

**Sample:**

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Builder;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace HelloMvc
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {                
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage(); // <=== that is missing

            app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args) => WebApplication.Run<Startup>(args);
    }
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/blob/v1.0.0-rc1-update1/samples/1.0.0-rc1-final/HelloMvc/Startup.cs)